# Replace String between characters X & Y

Tags: java

How can i make a code using java 14 to replace a specific string between the two given strings i give as parameter? Example in this line:

```
<set name="trait" val="DERANGEMENT" />
```

I want to create a method that accept two String as parameter. The first one will be `<set name="trait" val="` and the second `"` so whatever is between those two it will be replaced with something else.

Comment: If that's from a formally correct xml file use an xml parser, change the attribute value and re-write the file, instead.

Comment: You might use methods indexOf and substring (fromt the String class) to get what you want.

Comment: apache StringUtils.substringBetween may help.. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```java
String prefix = "<set name=\"trait\" val=\"";
String suffix = "\"";
String input = "Foo<set name=\"trait\" val=\"DERANGEMENT\" />Bar";
String replacement = "DISORDER";
```

```java
String output = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(prefix) + ".*?" + Pattern.quote(suffix),
                                 Matcher.quoteReplacement(prefix + replacement + suffix));
```

```java
System.out.println(output);
```

Alternatively, use `indexOf()`:

```java
String output = input;
int start = input.indexOf(prefix);
if (start != -1) {
    start += prefix.length();
    int end = input.indexOf(suffix, start);
    if (end != -1) {
        output = input.substring(0, start) + replacement + input.substring(end);
    }
}
```

*Output from both*

```
Foo<set name="trait" val="DISORDER" />Bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Would you like it to work like this?

Here you can check it how it works: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstPart = "<setname=\"trait\" val=\"";
        String secondPart = "\"";

        String fullString = "<setname=\"trait\" val=\"REMOVE_THIS_PART\"";
        String addThisToString = "I REPLACED TEXT TO THIS";

        String replaced = replace(firstPart, secondPart, fullString, addThisToString);
        System.out.println(replaced); // <setname="trait" val="I REPLACED TEXT TO THIS"
    }

    public static String replace(String firstPart, String secondPart, String fullString, String addThisToString) {
        String stringShouldBeRemoved = fullString.replace(firstPart, "").replace(secondPart, "");
        fullString = fullString.replace(stringShouldBeRemoved, addThisToString);

        return fullString;
    }
}
```